# LINQ to EF returning all columns and not passing WHERE clause to server

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm working with LINQ to Entities in Razor. I have something like this:

```
@foreach(Org o in Model) {
    @foreach(User u in o.Users.Where(x => x.Active==true) ) {
       <span> @u.FirstName </span>
    }
}
```

When I look at SQL server profiler, the query has two major inefficiencies:

1. It returns ALL columns in the Users table
2. It return ALL rows in the Users table, not just those with Active==true.

Of course it works okay but I was under the impression LINQ was cleverer than this and would send a more specific query to SQL server.

Question: Can I get LINQ to pass on the WHERE clause (Active==true) and also to only get the FirstName column automatically?

p.s. Unless strictly relevant I'm not so interested in whether or not LINQ in a view is good practice - eg if views are optimised differently to compiled code?

This is my Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    xyz_Entities db = new xyz_Entities();
    return PartialView(db.Orgs);
}
```

UPDATE - many apologies, this is actually a nested loop, which may be material.

Comment: You aren't properly disposing your data context. You can't dispose of it in the Controller if you intend to access db.Users from your view.

Comment: Ok - but would this in itself affect the problem I'm trying to solve?

Comment: No, but if you were to pass an `IQueryable<>` to the View, then your next problem would be that your DataContext is out of scope and an exception would be thrown by EF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It returns ALL columns in the Users table

Sure it does - Linq has no knowledge of you you plan to *use* the data - so it returns all of the columns.

> It return ALL rows in the Users table, not just those with Active==true.

I'm guessing this is because `Model` materializes ALL records in the controller by calling `ToList` or `AsEnumerable`.

To avoid these I would to the query in the controller instead of the view and pass the results as part of the model or in the `ViewData` dictionary. You could try paring down the query to:

```
var names = Model.Users.Where(x => x.Active==true)
                       .Select(u => u.FirstName)
                       .ToList();
ViewData["Names"] = names;
```

Comment: I've posted the controller code above - there's no ToList() but perhaps an implicit AsEnumerable as suggested by @Brian-Ball

Comment: @rwalter I would do more work in your controller and setup the model appropriately.  Ideally your "model" should contain the minimum of data needed to present the view.  If all you need is the `FirstName` then your model could be `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Thanks - I did a bit of playing around and discovered that even an `@o.Users.Count()` does a `SELECT * FROM Users`. It's a bit of a shame because I'd like to be able to quickly add another field to a view without having to make changes to the viewmodel and mapping and so on when putting together a quick prototype.

Comment: @rwalter `ViewData` is a quick way to add data without building a whole new model - but be careful not to abuse it as it's not strongly typed and thus vulnerable to run-time errors.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown where your model is populated, but that is where the data access is happening, and is why you are retrieving all users from the database.

By the time you get to this view, you have already populated your `Users` collection and so you just using LINQ to Objects with your in memory collection.

You will need to change your data access code that populates your model to apply the filter at the database query level.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably pulling all of the rows because either you are calling `ToList` or `ToArray` or because the declared type of `Model.Users` is `IEnumerable<>` instead of `IQueryable<>`. Calls to extension methods get rewritten by the compiler to be called like normal static methods, and the compiler uses the declared type to determine `IEnumerable<>` vs `IQueryable<>`.

Once you get the filtering issue fixed, you can tell EF exactly which columns you want returned by the query by using the `Select` extension method.

Comment: This sounds promising but I just tried your (correct-sounding) suggestion of changing `@model IEnumerable<Orgs>;` to `@model IQueryable<Orgs>;` and it hasn't made any difference as far as I can tell. Do I need to do something in the Controller, or Model?